# In which Magento version the Google ReCaptcha was introduced?

Tags: magento2, google, recaptcha

I'm very curious to know which Magento version consists default Google ReCaptcha module.

Comment: magento 2 has google recaptcha out of the box ?

Comment: I cant find the meaning of asking this question here.

Comment: @Marius yes it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the official documentation by Magento:

> The Google reCAPTCHA extension is bundled and installed with Magento Open Source and Magento Commerce 2.3.x.

[image]

Source link : [Google reCAPTCHA || Magento](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/security/google-recaptcha.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Google reCAPTCHA extension is installed with Magento from magento2.3.1

Refer [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.1Commerce.html#paypal-payflow-pro-active-carding-activity-update)